# Observables vs. variables in Angular 2 services

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a question regarding the use of Observables vs. variables in Angular 2 services. The former seems to be the preferred way, but I cannot find out why exactly.

Given a sample service such as this:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    // Method 1
    public data = {x: Math.random(), y: Math.random()};

    // Method 2
    private _data$:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({x: Math.random(), y: Math.random()});
    public data$:Observable<any> = this._data$.asObservable();

    constructor() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.data = {x: Math.random(), y: Math.random()};
            this._data$.next({x: Math.random(), y: Math.random()});
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

I have seen basically 2 ways of consuming data in a component. Just using a variable directly:

```
<pre>{{testService.data | json}}</pre>
```

And using an Observable:

```
<pre>{{(testService.data | async) | json}}</pre>
```

Both seem to work, so what's the advantage of using the more elaborate Observable-based approach?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/1qVDSZwq2NVgZsWFPnii?p=preview

Answer (score 15):

Observables push value changes to components and services that subscribe to changes.

A variable requires polling, Therefore it's a huge performance benefit.

Especially if there are timing issues, for example the component wants a value from a service that the service fetches from the server.
How does the component know about the value becoming available.

With an observable the component just subscribes and gets called when the value arrived.

Angulars change detection directly supports observables. 
When the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is used and the view binds to an observable using the async pipe (`<div>{{myObservable | async}}</div>`), then change detection is not run at all except when a new value is pushed by the observable.

Observables have other benefits.
See for example https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that observables are a stream, and you can have more than one subscriber to the stream. And you also get all the advantages of a stream - hot, cold obervables, reply, filters, etc.